# Ajax error render

Tags: forms, ajax

I receive this error message when I try my custom form in Drupal 8.

> User error: "0" is an invalid render array key in Drupal\Core\Render\Element::children()

This is the code I am using

```
namespace Drupal\drupalup_simple_form\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\HtmlCommand;

/**
 * Our simple form class.
 */
class SimpleForm extends FormBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'drupalup_simple_form';
  }


  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */

 public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['search'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Search:'),
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    '#button_type' => 'primary',
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => [$this, 'submitForm'],
      'event' => 'click',
    ),
  );
  return $form;
}



  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $url = 'http://example.se/api/json/1.0/searchProduct.json?query=';
    $term = $form_state->getValue('search');
    $query_url = $url. $term;
    $client =  \Drupal::httpClient();
    $request = $client->get($query_url);
    $data = json_decode($request->getBody(), TRUE);
    $results = [];
    if (!empty($data) && !empty($data['items'])) {
      foreach ($data['items'] as $item ) {
        $results[] = $item['name'];
      }
    }
    return $results;
     }
  }
?>
```

The end result should be that all results from the URL with the [searchword] are shown when you have entered the search word in the textfield and pressed submit.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: You can remove the ajax stuff on the submit button because FormBase calls submitForm automatically when you click a submit button.

Answer (score 0):

I think this error relates to using an ordinal array, rather than an associative array, for the `$results` variable.

I think you might be able to fix it by replacing this loop:

```
foreach ($data ['items'] as $item ) {
  $results[] = $item['name'];
}
```

With this one:

```
foreach ($data['items'] as $key => $item ) {
  $results[$key] = $item['name'];
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The error message isn't helping you out much here. In an ideal world it would be more like this:

> The value for element with key '0' is not an array, but also not NULL.

That would be more in-keeping with the logic that triggered the error in [`Element::children()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element.php/function/Element%3A%3Achildren/8.7.x), which is expecting each element whose key isn't prefixed with `#` to itself be a render array.

A valid render array can be formed with very little effort, changing your code to this should bring better luck:

```
foreach ($data['items'] as $key => $item ) {
  $results[] = ['#markup' => $item['name']];
}
```

See the [Render arrays](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/render-arrays) docs for more info.